# Java, Counting average from Database

Tags: java, database, average

I'm working on my project now but I have encountered some problems :/
My method is supposed to gather information from the database and then count the average. This is what I get so far:

```
Rate: 4
Food_Food_ID: 2
------------
Rate: 4
Food_Food_ID: 2
------------
Rate: 2
Food_Food_ID: 2
------------
Rate: 12
Food_Food_ID: 2
------------
Rate: 5
Food_Food_ID: 4
------------
Rate: 10
Food_Food_ID: 4
------------
Average: 6.166666666666667
```

(This is the average of all the Rates :/ )

But I'm trying to get:

```
Rate: 22
Food_Food_ID: 2
Average: 5.5

------------
Rate: 15
Food_Food_ID: 2
Average: 7.5
------------
```

It should add all of the rating and then count the average of the rating. I hope I explained it good :)

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/zUdF9HwF

First time posting here, hope I did okey. And thanks for the help :D

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that you didn't explained it good: as for me, I can not understand your issue.

Comment: Look out for `SUM` and `AVG` SQL functions. And also you would need `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: As one can see from your question is that you want the average by every food ID separately. Right?

Comment: `select avg(user.Rate) from user`
and `select avg(user.Rate), food.Food_Food_ID FROM user INNER JOIN food ON user.Food_Food_ID=food.Food_Food_ID group by food.Food_Food_ID`

Comment: Okey, lets say people can use my program to set a rank 1-5 on a restaurant. And I'm trying to grab the information and see what each restaurant got as an average rating. So Food_Food_ID 2 could be "Captain Pizza" and it got 2 votes that i'm trying to count on. God i am so bad at explaining ^_^

Comment: @Vic Yes that's what I want! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what SQL was invented for, see:

```
SELECT user.Food_Food_ID, AVG(user.Rate)
FROM user 
     INNER JOIN food ON user.Food_Food_ID = food.Food_Food_ID
GROUP BY user.Food_Food_ID
```

No loops, no counting, just one SQL and you get the results.

Comment: Yep.  SQL can do all of that math for you (and it does it very, very quickly if you structure your query correctly.)

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz Think I did it now ^^